# Stop clean-css from changing 'Crimson' to #dc143c in { font-type: 'Crimson Text' }

Tags: css, gulp-clean-css, clean-css

My project uses React, Isomorphic rendering, Gulp, and Webpack. We will be removing Gulp, but until then...

I am using the [styl](https://github.com/tj/styl) for css/sass and I'm having an issue. I bring in a local npm package which uses precompiled css. My project is dependent on this package.

When [gulp-clean-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clean-css) (which uses clean-css) compiles my main project, it is replacing `font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif` from the npm package with **`font-family: "#dc143c Text , serif"`** and I am having issues figuring out how to prevent it. [This clean-css link](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#level-1-optimizations) will be of use I believe ? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Or tell clean-css to ignore minifying this file entirely is an option

Comment: I am not familiar with the workings of clean-css, but this sounds like it's confused about whether things inside single quotes may be manipulated. Have you tried using double quotes instead? Or maybe there's a single quote somewhere earlier in the CSS that throws it off? An apostrophe in a comment perhaps?

Comment: Yes that was the first thing I tried :/ it's an issue that it is double compiled/minified. the first minification removes the quotes, the second interprets the unquoted color

Comment: Removing quotes around a font name I'd classify as a bug. Same as changing the value of a `font-name` property to something else. I don't think there's much you can do, except file a bug report.

Comment: @MrLister I agree, thank you!